# Debugging Google play services

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have installed Google play services on my application following the official documentation.

Everything seems fine and I tried to put the connect button using BaseGameUtils class.

But once I launch the application, I have an error saying to update Google Play Services app on my phone (The app is up to date).

So obviously there is something wrong there but I can't find what it is... Is there any way to track the error and know what's really wrong with Google Play ?

Comment: Update : I've still not found any solution. Does someone has any idea/suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably specified a too high version number of Google play services in build.gradle. I had the exact same problem (after Android studio suggested upgrading to a higher version). I fixed the problem by changing back to the old version in build.gradle.

I changed from

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
}
```

and it solved the issue.

Comment: I've tried with the version 5.0.89 but the problem is the same. Is there a way to know what is really wrong ?